# Windows 10 using WSL ubuntu cannot ping any address

Tags: ubuntu, ping, windows-subsystem-for-linux, packet-loss

I cannot ping any website when I am using WSL for windows 10.

```
--- google.com ping statistics ---
14 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 38567ms
```

is the result when I try ping google.com
I am using windows 10 with IPv4, disabled IPv6. I can ping google.com normally without wsl on my regular command prompt

Comment: Did you check if Windows Firewall blocks connection from WSL?

Comment: @Biswapriyo Where can i specify windows fire wall to allow WSL? My firewall is currently being used by Avast Internet security and I tried disabling Avast firewall but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Probably you've got some DNS issue, here is how I solved it:

Run on linux terminal:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

Then, you change the DNS IP to google's - 8.8.8.8, write the file.
[Example of the file you will need to edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YJso.png%5D%5B1%5D)

To assert, run:

```
$ ping google.com
```